# Word for something 'done out of anger'?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

Is there one word that suggests that something was 'done out of anger'? Usage similar to something done deliberately or intentionally, only including the motivation of anger.

Comment: Can you show us an example sentence where this word would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

: spitefully

in an unkind way in order to hurt or upset somebody
synonym maliciously
‘I don't need you,’ she said spitefully.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/spitefully?q=spitefully

Note: 'out of spite'
: a feeling of anger towards another person that makes someone want to annoy, upset, or hurt them, especially in a small way:
He's the sort of man who would let down the tyres on your car just out of/from spite.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spite

Regarding the context you provided in your comment "when a parent allows their child to do something. It's either generously granted, as in their divine will, or they permit it with sarcasm as if saying, "Go ahead, but just see what happens" , you could use "exasperatedly" :

"That child will be the death of me!" Despina complained exasperatedly as she pushed back her hair from her eyes.

https://www.foboko.com/sentence-dictionary/english/exasperatedly

Comment: Thank you. What am I'm trying to demonstrate is when a parent allows their child to do something. It's either generously granted, as in their divine will, or they permit it with sarcasm as if saying, "Go ahead, but just see what happens" as in their ........ will. Someone want to use the word permissive, but to me that is not showing the underlying motive.

Comment: @user175526 In the context you provided, ""That child will be the death of me!" Despina complained exasperatedly as she pushed back her hair from her eyes." https://www.foboko.com/sentence-dictionary/english/exasperatedly